# Cannot read property 'exists' of undefined from Jasmine to Angular services file

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I have an services file with add function.

> this.addFunction = function (item) {
>       ar existItem = $$("idOfItemInUI").exists(item);
>        }

from Jasmine, I want to call this services function.

> it("can add an item", function () {
>   var item= "abc";
>   servicesFile.addFunction(item); }

But it shows problem.
"Cannot read property 'exists' of undefined"

Could you help me?

Comment: That means `$$("idOfItemInUI")` is `undefined`. Do you mean to have 2x `$$` there?

Comment: Thanks for your response. It seem that we can't get that control from jasmine. $$("idOfItemInUI") which was defined at html template and was called from services. Now, I want to make a unitest from jasmine for push an item to GUI. Before I add, I want to check that this item exist or not.

Comment: How can we do? I research but didn't get it.

Comment: In your before each section, you can mock the value of  $$("idOfItemInUI"). So that it will not be undefined.

Comment: I solve problem. We need to create a component before call to services.